# AWS amplify error on signOut()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am unable to sign out from Cognito after connecting with AES Amplify via withAuthenticator.
The first time the app shows up, it presents the login screen. After logging in it works normally. Then if I call:

```
Auth.signOut()
```

It gives the error:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'this.credentials.clearCachedId')
```

and stays logged in. Same with the Greetings sign out buttom from Amplify. I just can't sign out. It seems to happen when using tab navigators.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think this have been solved in the latest version. Could you update the library and try again?